# OnDrawGizmos ставит неправильный радиус

Tags: unity3d

Почему гизмос рисует сферу больше чем нужно?

```
    private void OnDrawGizmos() 
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Scale объекта изменен?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский да был, спасибо. Забыл, что такой момент тоже важен. Теперь все нормально

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в размере объекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]